# Multiple url passing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

```
   browserName=chrome

   adminUrl =https://landingsite.webapp.com/
   AdminUserName =demoeu@yopmail.com
   AdminPwd = 1234

  landingUrl=https://testing.app.com/
  AdminUserName =demoeu@yopmail.com
  AdminPwd = 1234

  CustomerUrl=https://testing .app.com/
  AdminUserName =demo@yopmail.com
  AdminPwd = 1234
```

I am using three different URLs with same same names, because I am using 
  *AdminUserName* and *AdminPwd*  in another class. i don't want to execute all 
  scenarios at a time. I am trying to write if condition:

```
if(CustomerUrl=https://testing .app.com/)
 // here I want that username and that Password but here I am getting First 
  Username and Password I want only third Username and ThirdPassword
```

Stack people help highly needed please guide me

```
            public void loginAdminPortal()
               {
    String userName = prop.getProperty("AdminUserName");
    String password = prop.getProperty("AdminPwd");
    Generic.enterValue("id", AdminPortalOR.UserName, userName);
    Generic.enterValue("id", AdminPortalOR.password, password);

            }


      When I am passing third Url it is getting  FirstUserName and FIrst 
      Password i want third Username and Password
```

Comment: Do you have any code that is not working so that we could help you to fix issues?

Comment: Definitely, please post your existing code so we know what you actually need help with. You have this tagged java, but I don't see any Java code in this question. Otherwise, we'll have to send this question to The Wall.